# Divide the Table data randomly based on percentages

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Employees`, having 100 records. The columns are `ID` and `Name`.

100 is just a sample number, it can have any number of records like 15 or 115.
The sampling should be done based on the percentages given below.

Now I would like to add new column `Group`. `Group` value will be `Group1`, `Group2`, `Group3`.

How can assign the rows to groups so that each row is in a randomly chosen group, but the resulting distribution follows the below percentages.

```
65% Employees Should go to Group1
20% Employee Should go to Group2
15% Employee Should go to Group3
```

Comment: You are right. 100 is just an example, it should even when there 6 employee or 102 employees based on percentage samling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is similar to those form Michal and his answer is also correct, however NTILE to be used as alternative, since it will split a dataset to 100 equal chunks. ROW_Number will not work for a case for a dataset with a number of rows smaller than 100.:

```
select id,a.name,
       case when rn <= 65 then 'group 1'
            else case when rn <= 85 then 'group 2' else 'group 3' end
       end
from
(
    --newid() will generate random order of records
    select ID, name , NTILE(100) OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) [rn] from dbo.Employees
) [a]
```

Comment: any chance you can look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714621/assign-value-randomly-but-within-distributions-within-grouping

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this doesn't work if the number of records is less then 100. For example, with the windowing function, I get 1-8 if I have 8 records.

Comment: @mountainclimber, yes, you are right, it requires a hundred members or more to perform bucketing of the records into 100 chunks. I also changed my answer accordingly. This is because the query is hardcoded to expect 100 members. Nothing is wrong to parametrize and have logic more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Following query contains inner query, which will introduce row numbers, based on random order, generated by `newid()`. Then it's enough to assing in outer query `group 1` for rows between 1 and 65 (which is 65% of 100), `group 2` for row numbers between 66 and 85 (20%) and `group 3` for the rest (15%).

```
select id,name,
       case when rn <= 65 then 'group 1'
            else case when rn <= 85 then 'group 2' else 'group 3' end
       end
from
(
    --newid() will generate random order of records
    select ID, name, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by newid()) [rn] from Employees
) [a]
```

Comment: 100 is just sample number, if can have more or less number of employees as well. the sampling should be done based on percentages given.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE (ID INT,Name VARCHAR(100))

DECLARE @numRows int,@i int
SET @numRows = 100
SET @i=1

WHILE @i<@numRows
BEGIN
    INSERT @Employee(ID,Name) SELECT @i,'Test Name' +Convert(VARCHAR(10),@i)
    SET @i=@i+1
END

SELECT A.ID,A.Name,(CASE WHEN A.RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 65 THEN 'Group1'
                        WHEN A.RowNumber BETWEEN 66 AND 85 THEN 'Group2'
                        WHEN A.RowNUmber BETWEEN 86 AND 100 THEN 'Group3' ELSE '' END) 'Group' FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RowNUmber,ID,Name FROM @Employee) A
```