# Assign value randomly but within distributions within grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to assign a name to records randomly but based on a percent distribution. For example, say I have this data:

```
name    type sub_type reg pct
a       xx    yy      n    .7
a       xx    yy      n    .7
NO Name xx    yy      n    NULL
NO Name xx    yy      n    NULL
NO Name xx    yy      n    NULL
b       xx    yy      n    .3
NO Name xx    yy      n    NULL

a       bb    yy      n    .1
b       bb    yy      n    .8
c       bb    yy      n    .1
NO Name bb    yy      n    NULL

a       xx    cc      n    .1
a       xx    cc      n    .1
NO Name xx    cc      n    NULL
NO Name xx    cc      n    NULL
NO Name xx    cc      n    NULL
b       xx    cc      n    .9
NO Name xx    cc      n    NULL

a       bb    cc      n    .5
b       bb    cc      n    .2
c       bb    cc      n    .3
NO Name bb    cc      n    NULL

a       xx    cc      x    .2
a       xx    cc      x    .2
NO Name xx    cc      x    NULL
NO Name xx    cc      x    NULL
NO Name xx    cc      x    NULL
b       xx    cc      x    .8
NO Name xx    cc      x    NULL

a       bb    cc      x    .3
b       bb    cc      x    .1
c       bb    cc      x    .6
NO Name bb    cc      x    NULL
```

I want to assign the NO Name records a random name based on the pct distribution within the grouping of type, sub_type, and reg categories. So for example, the four NO Name records when type = xx, sub_type = cc and reg = n would be randomly assigned the name a or b but the resulting distribution of NO Name records within the type = xx, sub_type = cc and reg = n grouping would 70% for a's and 30% for b's since that is their pct value within that grouping. So randomly distribute the records by name by type/sub_type/reg grouping given the name pct assignment within that grouping.

The result might look something like this:

```
 name    type sub_type reg pct
a       xx    yy      n    .7
a       xx    yy      n    .7
a       xx    yy      n    NULL
a       xx    yy      n    NULL
a       xx    yy      n    NULL
b       xx    yy      n    .3
b       xx    yy      n    NULL

a       bb    yy      n    .1
b       bb    yy      n    .8
c       bb    yy      n    .1
b       bb    yy      n    NULL

a       xx    cc      n    .1
a       xx    cc      n    .1
b       xx    cc      n    NULL
b       xx    cc      n    NULL
b       xx    cc      n    NULL
b       xx    cc      n    .9
b       xx    cc      n    NULL

a       bb    cc      n    .5
b       bb    cc      n    .2
c       bb    cc      n    .3
a       bb    cc      n    NULL

a       xx    cc      x    .2
a       xx    cc      x    .2
b       xx    cc      x    NULL
b       xx    cc      x    NULL
b       xx    cc      x    NULL
b       xx    cc      x    .8
a       xx    cc      x    NULL

a       bb    cc      x    .3
b       bb    cc      x    .1
c       bb    cc      x    .6
c       bb    cc      x    NULL
```

I don't have enough records in my made up data to really show the distributions, but hopefully enough to illustrate my issue.

This is doing similar to what I want, but the percentages are fixed in this example and their isn't any groups like I have:
[Divide the Table data randomly based on percentages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531392/divide-the-table-data-randomly-based-on-percentages)

Hopefully that makes sense.

EDIT 1: I think I have part of the buckets part down

```
select
    xx.*
    ,NTILE((select count(*)
        from (
                select distinct 
                    REG
                ,TYPE
                ,SUB_TYPE 
                from tbl1
                group by
                REG
                ,TYPE
                ,SUB_TYPE ) x))
        over (partition by REG
                    ,TYPE
                    ,SUB_TYPE order by newid()) buckets
    from tbl1 xx
```

Comment: What makes up your "groups"? They look like random rows grouped together as there doesn't appear to be anything that distinguishes them apart. And given that you have all three names in each group it doesn't seem to matter much what name you provide.

Comment: I added a space in the data for clarity. The groupings are type/sub_type/reg

Comment: That helps considerably. This doesn't appear to be all that different than the one you linked.

Comment: In concept it isn't but I can't sort out how to do it for my situation.

Comment: Do you have a PK on the table, like an Id column, to identify a record?

Comment: Yes I do.................

Comment: Any help would be much appropriated!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this snippet returns a result you are looking for

It has a slightly different logic from some my other answer you made a reference earlier. However, I believe in a current case `ROW_NUMBER` is a more appropriate alternative to `NTILE`

```
;WITH cte  ([name], [type], sub_type, reg, pct)
AS 
(
SELECT 'a', 'xx', 'yy', 'n',  .7           UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 'xx', 'yy', 'n',  .7           UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO Name', 'xx', 'yy', 'n',  NULL   UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO Name', 'xx', 'yy', 'n',  NULL   UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO Name', 'xx', 'yy', 'n',  NULL   UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 'xx', 'yy', 'n',  .3           UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO Name', 'xx', 'yy', 'n',  NULL   UNION ALL

SELECT 'a', 'bb', 'yy', 'n',  .1           UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 'bb', 'yy', 'n',  .8           UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 'bb', 'yy', 'n',  .1           UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO Name', 'bb', 'yy', 'n',  NULL   UNION ALL

SELECT 'a', 'xx', 'cc', 'n',  .1           UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 'xx', 'cc', 'n',  .1           UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO Name', 'xx', 'cc', 'n',  NULL   UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO Name', 'xx', 'cc', 'n',  NULL   UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO Name', 'xx', 'cc', 'n',  NULL   UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 'xx', 'cc', 'n',  .9           UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO Name', 'xx', 'cc', 'n',  NULL   UNION ALL

SELECT 'a', 'bb', 'cc', 'n',  .5           UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 'bb', 'cc', 'n',  .2           UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 'bb', 'cc', 'n',  .3           UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO Name', 'bb', 'cc', 'n',  NULL   UNION ALL

SELECT 'a', 'xx', 'cc', 'x',  .2           UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 'xx', 'cc', 'x',  .2           UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO Name', 'xx', 'cc', 'x',  NULL   UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO Name', 'xx', 'cc', 'x',  NULL   UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO Name', 'xx', 'cc', 'x',  NULL   UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 'xx', 'cc', 'x',  .8           UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO Name', 'xx', 'cc', 'x',  NULL   UNION ALL

SELECT 'a', 'bb', 'cc', 'x',  .3           UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 'bb', 'cc', 'x',  .1           UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 'bb', 'cc', 'x',  .6           UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO Name', 'bb', 'cc', 'x',  NULL   

) 

-- Records without name
SELECT CASE             
            WHEN d.TotalRecordsInGroup  = 1 THEN 'a' --only one record in the group
            WHEN d.RecordNr/CAST(d.TotalRecordsInGroup AS FLOAT) < .7 THEN 'a'
            WHEN d.RecordNr/CAST(d.TotalRecordsInGroup AS FLOAT) <= 1.0 THEN 'b'

            ELSE NULL 
        END  AS [name]
            ,
       d.type,
       d.sub_type,
       d.reg,
       d.pct       
FROM (
SELECT cte.name
,       cte.type
,       cte.sub_type
,       cte.reg
,       cte.pct
        -- obtain record number randomly of members in a group
,       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type, cte.sub_type,reg ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RecordNr
        -- obtain the numbers of members in a group
,       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY type, cte.sub_type,reg) AS TotalRecordsInGroup 
FROM cte 
WHERE cte.name = 'No Name'
) d
UNION ALL
-- Records with a known name
SELECT cte.name,
       cte.type,
       cte.sub_type,
       cte.reg,
       cte.pct 
FROM cte
WHERE cte.name <> 'No Name'
ORDER BY d.type, sub_type, reg
```