# I have to use 80/20 on the given result in SQL. There are some resources available, but I am still not able to digress them

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

```
select o.user_id, liftime_orders from
((select distinct user_id from app_open
 WHERE DATE (TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + TIME*INTERVAL '0.001 second') BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE -30 AND CURRENT_DATE) a
JOIN

(select COUNT (distinct order_num) AS liftime_orders,user_id
from order_master_bi
group by 2
having  liftime_orders >=1
) o

ON a.user_id=o.user_id)
```

database is amazon redshift

[the result for his query]]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMThz.png

Comment: Show is some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images, no links.) Simplify if you can, make it easy to assist you. [mcve].

Comment: just need to divide users (user_id) into 80:20 on the basis of liftime_orders. so 3 columns, 1 with all user_id,next with 80% users and another with 20%

Comment: What do you mean by "divide users"? Please show an example of what you expect the output to be (in text, not pictures).

Comment: I finally got the output, It is somewhat similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531392/divide-the-table-data-randomly-based-on-percentages

Comment: This question is totally unclear, and most likely a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from a previous answer of stackoverflow itself.
Please refer to this link : [Divide the Table data randomly based on percentages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531392/divide-the-table-data-randomly-based-on-percentages)

SELECT users,
MAX(rn) OVER () AS max_rnk,
CASE
WHEN max_rnk * 0.8 <= rn THEN 'test'
ELSE 'control'
END AS flag
FROM (SELECT o.user_id AS users,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY random ()) AS rn
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM app_open
WHERE DATE (TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + TIME*INTERVAL '0.001 second') BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE -30 AND CURRENT_DATE) a
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT order_num) AS liftime_orders,
user_id
FROM order_master_bi
GROUP BY 2
HAVING liftime_orders >= 1) o ON a.user_id = o.user_id)